# Esbuild, global module and Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, esbuild

I have created a new `src/index.js` script like this:

```
export function myFunction() {
  alert("Hello!")
}
```

I built it using esbuild (0.18.6) with the following configuration:

```
const esbuild = require('esbuild');

esbuild.build({
  entryPoints: ['./src/index.js'],
  outfile: './dist/index.js',
  bundle: true,
  sourcemap: 'external',
  minify: true,
  globalName: 'xyz',
  loader: {
    '.js': 'jsx'
  }
}).catch(() => process.exit(1));
```

I'm calling this script inside an HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="./dist/index.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onClick="xyz.myFunction()">Hello</button> <!-- CORRECT. It display the alert message. -->

    <script>
      xyz.myFunction(); /* Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: xyz is not defined */
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I run xyz.myFunction() inside the browser (Chrome 114), it executes correctly. However, when it is called within the script tag, I receive the error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: xyz is not defined". How can I solve this issue? Thank you very much.

**Edited**: I solved it by removing the 'defer' attribute within the script tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first script element uses [the `defer` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#defer):

> This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but before firing DOMContentLoaded.

But your other script element tries to access `xyz` **during** the parse phase, which is **before** the first script will have been executed.

Don't `defer` the first script until after you need it.

---

I recommend calling your function directly and using `addEventListener` for event binding inside your bundled script **instead** of making `xyz` a global and using `onclick` attributes and second `<script>` elements.

Comment: I just realized that I wasted a bunch of time. Thank you :D